# Firebase Timestamp toDate function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hi coders I need some help with a date formation from a reactive froms value
as a date into a timestamp for firebase, and then read it out as a date again.

As I load the component I call a quick method to get me the user from my service, and save the result into a default Forms object with all my forms values which I then want to push later back to firebase, but upon loading I´ll need to convert the timestamp from firebase back to a toDate() if its there.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

this.auth.user.subscribe((user: any) => {
  if (user) {
    this.userDataService.getUserDetails(user).then(result => {
      this.initProfile(result);
      this.profileForm.value.appranticeInfos.birthday = this.profileForm.value.appranticeInfos.birthday.toDate();
      this.profileForm.value.educationinfos.educationStart = this.profileForm.value.educationinfos.educationStart.toDate();
      this.profileForm.value.educationinfos.educationEnd = this.profileForm.value.educationinfos.educationEnd.toDate();
    });
  }
});
```

}

my save method ( init with a save button on the end of the form)

```
save() {
console.log(this.profileForm.value);
this.profileForm.value.appranticeInfos.birthday = new Timestamp(Number(moment(this.profileForm.value.appranticeInfos.birthday).format('X')), 0);
this.profileForm.value.educationinfos.educationStart = new Timestamp(Number(moment(this.profileForm.value.educationinfos.educationStart).format('X')), 0);
this.profileForm.value.educationinfos.educationEnd = new Timestamp(Number(moment(this.profileForm.value.educationinfos.educationEnd).format('X')), 0)
this.userDataService.updateUserDetailsFormular(this.profileForm.value);
```

};

in the end you see the update method where i hand over all of the Formgroup.values

```
 async updateUserDetailsFormular(user: iUser) {
const docRef = doc(this.firestore, `users/${user.uid}`);
return setDoc(docRef, user, { merge: true });
```

}

My Formgroup, just a snipped out of it i got 4 Formgroups all togeter:

```
 initProfile(data?: iUser) {
this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
  companyInfos: new FormGroup({
    company: new FormControl((data?.companyInfos) ? data.companyInfos.company : ''),
    department: new FormControl((data?.companyInfos?.department) ? data.companyInfos.department : ''),
    companyStreet: new FormControl((data?.companyInfos?.companyStreet) ? data.companyInfos.companyStreet : ''),
    companyPost: new FormControl((data?.companyInfos?.companyPost) ? data.companyInfos.companyPost : ''),
    companyCity: new FormControl((data?.companyInfos?.companyCity) ? data.companyInfos.companyCity : ''),
    trainer: new FormControl((data?.companyInfos?.trainer) ? data.companyInfos.trainer : ''),
    trainingOfficer: new FormControl((data?.companyInfos?.trainingOfficer) ? data.companyInfos.trainingOfficer : ''),
    externalTrainer: new FormControl((data?.companyInfos?.externalTrainer) ? data.companyInfos.externalTrainer : ''),
  }),
```

but every time I want to save i get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.profileForm.value.appranticeInfos.birthday.toDate is not a function
TypeError: this.profileForm.value.appranticeInfos.birthday.toDate is not a function
```

link to the stackblitz app :
https://stackblitz.com/github/DWF-IT-P/IT-laIsland?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: can you share your form code ?

Comment: @Vignesh done, see above

Answer (score 0):

the issue with your code is while you patch value to value

in reactive form you  should not use readonly property to set values instead you need to use setValue or patchvalue to set the value

for example:

```
this.profileForm.get('companyInfos').get('company').setValue(new Timestamp(Number(moment(this.profileForm.value.appranticeInfos.birthday).format('X')), 0));
```

similar way you can do it for the **appranticeInfos**

Comment: not sure if it hase something to do with this, but ill get an error when im trying your way, 
ERROR: ts could be `NULL`
its because i set all of the values as optional in the form or as of type any for all the three datepicker, cause i had problems with that aswell

Comment: can you create a stackblitz code and send it ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/DWF-IT-P/IT-laIsland?file=src/app/app.component.ts

there you go, youll find everything i mentioned in Modules/Profile
or just download the project, i see right now it takes to long in the browser to build